# PHP Mailer SMTP Connection Refused on GoDaddy Server

Tags: php, email

I have using phpmailer(smtp) for sending email. My website is hosted on Godaddy.
I have read that phpmailer is not working with Godaddy. So tried multiple solutions to send email. But nothing worked. **Error message shows** 
**SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)SMTP Connect() failed.**

adding here code, help to resolve issue.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';;
$body = 'Hi this is test message';
$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net"; // SMTP server            
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;  
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "name@domain.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "*****";

$mail->SetFrom('name@domain.com', 'Web developer');

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";
 $mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = "toname@domain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
```

?>

Comment: any errors returned?

Comment: Check if PEAR Mail is installed on the server, if it is you can use it as alternative to PHPMailer. https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.php

Comment: try sending it ur mail id like this and check if its wrking. if it is snot working then lets try something else $toMail = "yourmailid@gmail.com";

Comment: @Mohammad error displays as **SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed.**

Comment: @rahulpatel tried mail id as gmail id. But giving the same error

Answer (score 2):

Setting the SMTPOptions solves my problem.

```
 <?php
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';;
 $body = 'Hi this is test message';
 $mail             = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
 $mail->SMTPOptions = [
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
        ],
    ];
  $mail->Host       = "mail.domain.com"; // SMTP server            
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;  
  $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->SMTPSecure = ''; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
  $mail->Port = 587;

  $mail->Username   = "name@domain.com"; // SMTP account username
  $mail->Password   = "*****";

  $mail->SetFrom('name@domain.com', 'Web developer');

  $mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);
  $address = "toname@domain.com";
  $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");
  if(!$mail->Send()) {
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   } else {
     echo "Message sent!";
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the MX record settings and check once.
In the cPanel Mail section Search for MX Entry Maintenance.
Then Select the related domain and Change Email Routing to Remote Mail Exchanger.
Add all the google MX records as they are in your domain configuration.
For more details on how to configure domain [Click here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125)

And set SMTP_SERVER as localhost like this SMTP_SERVER: localhost